# Integration Substitution rule, an example.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve this with the SUBSTITUTION RULE?  Please make an step-by-step solution with explanation.  Thank you!

$$ \int u^3 \sqrt{u^4+2} \, du $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x=2+u^4$, therefore $dx=4u^3$

So, now you get:  $$\frac14\int\sqrt{x}\ dx=\frac{x^{3/2}}6+C, \text{ where $C$ is a constant}$$

Now, just substitute back for $x=2+u^4$.

You should get:

$$\frac{x^{3/2}}6+C=\boxed{\frac16(2+u^4)^{3/2}+C}$$